# In Docker, how do I detect from inside a container, that if a file or a directory is mounted by the Docker?

Tags: docker

I did `docker-compose down`/`docker container rm` and noticed that I lost all my data created in the container. Yes, I forgot to mount my local directory as a volume in the first place.

To prevent this, on startup, I want to warn users that "the data will be non-persistent", if the local volume's not mounted.

**Is there a way to detect from inside container whether a file or a directory is a mounted one via Docker?**

I googled it but couldn't find a good way. And my current workaround is:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN \
  mkdir /data && \
  touch /data/.replaceme
...

ENTRYPOINT /detect-mount-and-start.sh
```

`detect-mount-and-start.sh` checks if `/data/.replaceme` exists. If so, it warns to mount a local volume and exits.

Are there a better way to detect it?

<sup>**Note (2019/09/12)**: This container is not only used via `docker-compose up` but `docker run --rm` too. And the directory name in local are not specified. Meaning, it can be `-v $(pwd)/mydata:/data` or something like `-v $(pwd)/data_local:/data`, etc.</sup>

<sup>**Note (2019/09/15)**: The situation is: I launched a container of Markdown Editor and created something like 100 of `.md` files. Those files were saved on `/data` on the root of the container. I should have mounted the volume like `-v $(pwd)/data:/data` before everything. But I didn't ... and noticed it after removing the container. My bad I know.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing may also work, but I was working with one of my client on a project in development environment, It was nodejs based application and they need to make sure the `server.js` exist before starting the container and `server.js` was expected from  mount location so I came up with this approach, As I did not find a way to sense shared docker volume inside container.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
run mkdir -p /myapp
copy . /myapp
copy entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
APP_PATH="/myapp"
files=$(ls /myapp/*.js)
echo "Files in Docker mount location:  $files"
  if [ -f "$APP_PATH/server.js" ] && [ -f "$APP_PATH/index.js" ]; then
    echo "Starting container with host mount files"
    echo "Starting server.js"
    cd $APP_PATH;
    node server.js
  else
    >&2 echo "Error: Pls mount the host location on /myapp path of the container i.e -v host_node_project:/myapp. Current files $(ls $APP_PATH)"
    break
  fi
```

build and run

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run -it --rm --name myapp myapp
```

[image]

Comment: Your situation is very similar to mine and better workaround! I was hoping if there's a file or info to tell us which files or directory was mounted. Something like the  `/.dockerenv` file in the root of the container which tells us if it's running under Docker.

Comment: yes exactly, just replace the name which you are expecting to be present in the mount directory. in my case, I was expecting `server.js`

Comment: @KEINOS you can accept the answer if it working with you or any suggestion for improvement will be appreciated

Comment: I'll wait for a little longer for other suggestions. There might be a surprising way to detect that. But, sofar your answer suits best! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I understand your question, but when you use docker-compose down, depending on how you create your **docker-compose.yml**, it will destroy your data, see:

**Will delete you data** when you execute down:

```
version: '2'
   mysqldb:
     image: mysql: 5.7
```

**Don't will delete** when you execute down:

```
version: '2'
   mysqldb:
     image: mysql: 5.7
     volumes:
       - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

**Don't will delete** when you execute down:

```
version: '2'
   mysqldb:
     image: mysql: 5.7
     volumes:
       - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
   data-volume:
     external: true
```

PS: I do not have a rating to comment on your question, so I am answering.

Comment: Thank you, your solution will help if it's `docker-compose` specific. But I should've described in more details, sorry. The container requires the local dir to be mounted as a volume, but not strictly via docker-compose. It can be run via `docker run` too. There fore I wanted to be sure if the file or the directory was mounted as a "mistake-proofing".

Comment: To mount the directory via `docker run`, you can use the -v parameter:`docker run -d --name=mysql -p 3306:3306 -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7`. I still don't understand why you need to do this manual check. The docker already deals with the creation or not of a volume, does not delete files if the volume already exists, it keeps the structure as it is. If you can make it clear why you need it (check manually when creating a directory), maybe I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for my English. Suppose I run `docker run -d --name=mysql -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7`, which `-v mysql-data`, the volume suppose to be mounted, was forgotten, and worked out something then exit. Will this still keep my data alive in local? If not, I want to warn the users who forgot to mount before they start working.

Comment: For example, run this command `docker run -d --name=mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7`. Connect on database  (**localhost, 3306, root / root**) and create new table. Run `docker container rm mysql -f` and `docker run ...` again WITHOUT parameter **volume**, looks the database/table created before and confirm that it does not exist, execute again `docker run ...` WITH parameter **volume** and check that the database/table is presents. See that he did not delete your table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following your steps 1(with), 2(without) and 3(with), I understand that the data is present in step 3 but in 2. Since the data created in step 1 exists on local. But what about someone starts with step 2(without) and work out something and then step 1(with)? All the tables and data created in step 2 will be lost, isn't it? Therefore I wanted to find out from inside the container if `/var/lib/mysql`, in this case, is the mounted volume before executing the main program. By the way, my container doesn't use DB though -> I will add the situation in the question about it.

Comment: I did clarify the question a little. See changes -> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57863638/revisions

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose stop - doesn't destroy your containers

Then you can use:

docker-compose start

Comment: Indeed. `start` then `stop` and check the changes in local and finally `down` would be the practice. But you know, I don't trust my self ... Sure I will do the same mistake ;-)